# Fine Uploader S3, Large files, ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm using Fine Uploader to upload directly to S3. It works for small files, but anything large, like 6GB causes the following error in the javascript console:
[screen shot of javascript Err_name_not_resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xRyz.png)

Here I'm uploading a file named "6gb".

This is the server log (Ruby on Rails). The first time the signature is requested, when uploading part#1:

```
Started POST "/signature" for 192.168.188.129 at 2016-01-31 00:51:12 +0000
Processing by UploadsController#signature as JSON
  Parameters: {"headers"=>"PUT\n\n\n\nx-amz-date:Sun, 31 Jan 2016 00:51:14 GMT\n/bv-deliverables/uploadsFolder/7c54325c-1db6-4d66-a31f-ceecb3c4ee2a.6gb?partNumber=1&uploadId=AD7mVbSzuhyC9JhgmZVu7dGEr5mJuEh8EpZTmx4Tl5M6r3ki6YDJvBqLfkDzFLQJGBpKGpzbwC8uPo7h3JGwQA--", "upload"=>{}}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

This POST to /signature is repeated for each part, up to part#133, where retry.gif is loaded, and the error in javascript console appears.

```
Started POST "/signature" for 192.168.188.129 at 2016-01-31 01:34:36 +0000
Processing by UploadsController#signature as JSON
  Parameters: {"headers"=>"PUT\n\n\n\nx-amz-date:Sun, 31 Jan 2016 01:34:37 GMT\n/bv-deliverables/uploadsFolder/7c54325c-1db6-4d66-a31f-ceecb3c4ee2a.6gb?partNumber=133&uploadId=AD7mVbSzuhyC9JhgmZVu7dGEr5mJuEh8EpZTmx4Tl5M6r3ki6YDJvBqLfkDzFLQJGBpKGpzbwC8uPo7h3JGwQA--", "upload"=>{}}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/retry.gif" for 192.168.188.129 at 2016-01-31 01:35:16 +0000
```

I believe I'm correctly signing the header, as it seems to work up until that part.

My upload speed is around 2 megabits per second.

Here is my AWS CORS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And here is my Fine uploader javascript:

```
    $('#fine-uploader-s3').fineUploaderS3({
        template: 'qq-template-s3',
        request: {
            endpoint: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bv-deliverables",
            accessKey: "AKIAILA4KWEGIGGBAL5Q"
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: "signature",
            customHeaders: {"X-CSRF-Token":"<%= form_authenticity_token %>"}
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: "create",
            customHeaders: {"X-CSRF-Token":"<%= form_authenticity_token %>"},
            params: {
                isBrowserPreviewCapable: qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews
            }
        },
        iframeSupport: {
            localBlankPagePath: "/server/success.html"
        },
        cors: {
            expected: true
        },
        chunking: {
            enabled: true
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: false
        },
        validation: {
            itemLimit: 5,
            sizeLimit: 107374182400
        },
        objectProperties: {
            reducedRedundancy: true,
            key: function (fileId) {

                var filename = $('#fine-uploader-s3').fineUploader('getName', fileId);
                var uuid = $('#fine-uploader-s3').fineUploader('getUuid', fileId);
                console.log(fileId);
                var ext = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

               return  'uploadsFolder/' + uuid + '.' + ext;
            }
        },
        callbacks: {
            onComplete: function(id, name, response) {
                var previewLink = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('preview-link')[0];
                location.reload();
                if (response.success) {

                    previewLink.setAttribute("href", response.tempLink)
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Re-adding the failed file seems to resume the upload at where it failed.

Again, it works perfectly with small files (like 15KB), and smaller multipart files (like 10MB), but the error occurs when I try to upload a large 6GB file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty clearly a network issue, outside of the control of Fine Uploader. The [auto retry feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/retry.html), if enabled, should attempt to resume automatically. Failing that, you can manually retry the upload using the [retry API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#retry), or the retry button that can be enabled with Fine Uploader UI.